# take some X,Y data - fit a function to it (with trailing ends) - sample that function as a pdf

Tags: python, interpolation, kernel-density

MAIN QUESTION:

Take some x,y data as tuples [(1,2), (3,4), ...]

[image]

interpolate a function[image]

add some trailing ends[image]

Then sample that new function as a probability density.

[Gaussian kernel density estimators](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) have the desired tails, and it even comes with a .resample() method - so they seem like a great option until I realize they only work on histogram data. So then the question becomes: Is it possible to somehow get (x,y) data points into some sort of histogram?